# How do I make my image move by hold the key and not repetitively pressing

Tags: javascript, image, move

here is my code

```
    function leftArrowPressed() {
          document.getElementById("image1").src = "http://orig04.deviantart.net/137f/f/2014/147/3/1/random_character__jet_bear_by_mnrart-d7jwteg.gif";
            var element = document.getElementById("image1");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 80 + 'px';
        }

        function rightArrowPressed() {
          document.getElementById("image1").src = "http://i.imgur.com/bZTh3Lk.gif";
          var element = document.getElementById("image1");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 80 + 'px';
        }


         function upArrowPressed() {
          document.getElementById("image1").src = "http://orig04.deviantart.net/137f/f/2014/147/3/1/random_character__jet_bear_by_mnrart-d7jwteg.gif";
          var element = document.getElementById("image1");
            element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 80 + 'px';
        }


         function downArrowPressed() {
          document.getElementById("image1").src = "http://i.imgur.com/bZTh3Lk.gif";
          var element = document.getElementById("image1");
            element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 80 + 'px';
        }

        function moveSelection(event) {                    
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                    leftArrowPressed();
                break;


                case 39:
                    rightArrowPressed();
                break; 

                case 38:
                    upArrowPressed();
                break;

                case 40:
                    downArrowPressed();
                break;
```

Currently i have to keep pressing and releasing to make it move i want to be able to hold the key down

Comment: You haven't included the code where you've created the key press event handlers

Comment: Perhaps try using the onkeydown() event objects to trigger moveSelection() and have it on a requestAnimationFrame loop where onkeyup() cancels the animationframe.

Comment: Quick suggestion but looping the sequence as suggested by Alexander with your current code would cause thrashing. Perhaps you should cache the top style value and use that instead of querying and writing repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use window.setInterval

define a global variable:

```
var timerId = null;
```

for each of your functions change:

```
case 37:
     leftArrowPressed();
```

To

```
   case 37:
      leftArrowAnimate();
```

And define leftArrowAnimate() as

```
// this will fire leftArrowPressed every 100 milliseconds
function leftArrowAnimate()
{
     timerId = window.setTimeout(leftArrowPressed(), 100);
}
```

Finally, you will need to also capture the key up event and stop the timer:

```
 // handle the key up event
 function moveSelectionFinished(event) {                    
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                window.clearTimeout(timerId);
            break;
// etc...
```

Comment: Instead of setTimeout you could also use requestAnimationFrame to improve the animation performance.

Comment: That may be a smoother if you only care about supporting modern browsers with the caveat that you will need capture the key and the state (up/down) in global variables to cancel and start the animation.

Comment: That's when [polyfills](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) come into the picture.

Answer (score 0):

1.- You can declare a global variable storing the direction. (i am using strings in order to made the code easy to understand)

```
var dir = "none";
```

2.- Now, in your "moveSelection" function you can change this value.

3.- Use setInterval to execute a function each X miliseconds, in this function move the image to the direction stored in the global variable. example:

```
function mainLoop()
{ 
    if(dir == "right")
        MoveToright()
    else if (dir == "up")
        MoveUp();
}

setInterval (mainLoop, 100) ; // 100 ms
```

Comment: this code is simpler, but i prefeer the Alexander H.'s code becouse when you do not press any button, there is no function running in background